# Error non-200 status code (401) SNScrapper Twitter

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, twitterapi-python

I used the python snscrapper to scrape data from twitter. I require to change the query keywords many time in order to get the data I want. Sometimes I get the result from scrapping, but most of the time it will say error non-200 status code(401). I googled for 401 error, and it says relating to access authorization. Now I cannot scrape the data from Twitter.

For your information, the snscrapper does not use Twitter API.

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd
import csv

tweets = []
query = '"MRT" AND "time" near:"Kuala Lumpur" until:2023-04-20 since:2022-11-01'

for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    # Replace any '\n' characters in the tweet text with the string '\\n'
    text = tweet.rawContent.replace('\n', '\\n')
    tweets.append([tweet.date, tweet.url, tweet.user.username, text])

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Date', 'Tweet URL', 'User','Tweet'])
print(df)

# Open the output CSV file in 'w' mode with newline='' argument
with open('MRT time Kuala Lumpur 1Nov22 to 20Apr23.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    # Use csv.writer to write rows to the CSV file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Tweet URL', 'User', 'Tweet'])
    for tweet in tweets:
        writer.writerow(tweet)
```

I am expecting that every time I scrape, there is no 401 error and can extract data without issues.